# Move title to the bottom with CSS

Tags: html, css

How can I move the title to the bottom on screen on max-width 640px without changing the structure on the html file?

```css
#header-image {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header-title {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 255px;
  right: 50px;
  text-align: left
}

.bottom-bar {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background- color: #007cb0;
}

.screen-480 {
  display: none;
}

.screen-768 {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480) {
  .screen-480 {
    display: block;
  }
  .screen-768 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header-image">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="header-title">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x683.png" width="100%" class="screen-
    480" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1028x550.png" width="100%" class="screen-
    768" alt="img" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having a `top:25%`, make it a bottom instead and put the amount of how far you want it to be from the bottom. I also altered the code to make it centered at the bottom, if that's what you wanted.

```css
#header-image {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header-title {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 255px;
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
}

.bottom-bar {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #007cb0;
}

.screen-480 {
  display: none;
}

.screen-768 {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480) {
  .screen-480 {
    display: block;
  }
  .screen-768 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header-image">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="header-title">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x683.png" width="100%" class="screen-
    480" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1028x550.png" width="100%" class="screen-
    768" alt="img" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .header-title{
      bottom:0;
      top:initial;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To align something to the `bottom`, one can set the `position` to `absolute` and `bottom` to `0px.` This will align it to `bottom` of the first parent that is positioned either absolute or relative.

```css
#header-image {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.header-title {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
  width: 255px;
  right: 50px;
  text-align: left
}

.bottom-bar {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background- color: #007cb0;
}

.screen-480 {
  display: none;
}

.screen-768 {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480) {
  .screen-480 {
    display: block;
  }
  .screen-768 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header-image">
  <div class="image">
    <div class="header-title">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/480x683.png" width="100%" class="screen-
    480" alt="img" />
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1028x550.png" width="100%" class="screen-
    768" alt="img" />
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-bar"></div>
</div>
```